# Can passed nightwatch.js tests be hidden in output?

Tags: nightwatch.js

The default Nightwatch.js output consumes one line per passed test. For example,

```
✔ Testing if element <body> contains text 'lecture is so boring' (12ms)
✔ Testing if element <button[id=btn1]> is visible (6ms)
✔ Testing if element <button[id=btn]> is visible (10ms)
✔ Testing if element <#fill1> is visible (19ms)
✔ Testing if element <#fill2> is visible (18ms)
✔ Testing if element <#fill3> is visible (20ms)
```

Currently Nightwatch consumes far more of my screen than the rest of my build output combined. On the CLI on Linux, appending

```
|grep -v "✔"
```

to the command mostly alleviates that but has the disadvantage of stripping colored text (even with --color=always) when calling nightwatch from gulp. Is there a configuration option or command line parameter to minimize output and only show failed tests?

Ideally, if all tests pass, I would prefer just one line of output, but that may be asking too much. Using the grep above, this still results, which remains too much for my taste.

```
[Nightwatch] Test Suite
=======================
ℹ Connected to localhost on port 4444 (1133ms).
  Using: firefox (91.0.1) on linux 4.19.0-18-amd64 platform.

Running:  Demo of Quiz


OK. 51 assertions passed. (3.498s)
```

I'd really just like it to say

```
Nightwatch: 51 assertions passed. (3.498s)
```

or similar.

My config file:

```
// Autogenerated by Nightwatch
// Refer to the online docs for more details: https://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/configuration/
const Services = {}; loadServices();

module.exports = {
  // An array of folders (excluding subfolders) where your tests are located;
  // if this is not specified, the test source must be passed as the second argument to the test runner.
  src_folders: ['src/ts/test/functional'],

  // See https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/working-with-page-objects/
  page_objects_path: '',

  // See https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/extending-nightwatch/#writing-custom-commands
  custom_commands_path:  '',

  // See https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/extending-nightwatch/#writing-custom-assertions
  custom_assertions_path: '',

  // See https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/#external-globals
  globals_path : '',

  webdriver: {},

  test_settings: {
    default: {
      disable_error_log: false,
      launch_url: 'https://nightwatchjs.org',

      screenshots: {
        enabled: false,
        path: 'screens',
        on_failure: true
      },

      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName : 'firefox'
      },

      webdriver: {
        start_process: true,
        server_path: (Services.geckodriver ? Services.geckodriver.path : '')
      }
    },



    firefox: {
      desiredCapabilities : {
        browserName : 'firefox',
        alwaysMatch: {
          // Enable this if you encounter unexpected SSL certificate errors in Firefox
          // acceptInsecureCerts: true,
          'moz:firefoxOptions': {
            args: [
              // '-headless',
              // '-verbose'
            ],
          }
        }
      },
      webdriver: {
        start_process: true,
        port: 4444,
        server_path: (Services.geckodriver ? Services.geckodriver.path : ''),
        cli_args: [
          // very verbose geckodriver logs
          // '-vv'
        ]
      }
    },

    chrome: {
      desiredCapabilities : {
        browserName : 'chrome',
        chromeOptions : {
          // This tells Chromedriver to run using the legacy JSONWire protocol (not required in Chrome 78)
          // w3c: false,
          // More info on Chromedriver: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/
          args: [
            //'--no-sandbox',
            //'--ignore-certificate-errors',
            //'--allow-insecure-localhost',
            //'--headless'
          ]
        }
      },

      webdriver: {
        start_process: true,
        port: 9515,
        server_path: (Services.chromedriver ? Services.chromedriver.path : ''),
        cli_args: [
          // --verbose
        ]
      }
    },

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Configuration for when using the browserstack.com cloud service               |
    //                                                                               |
    // Please set the username and access key by setting the environment variables:  |
    // - BROWSERSTACK_USER                                                           |
    // - BROWSERSTACK_KEY                                                            |
    // .env files are supported                                                      |
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    browserstack: {
      selenium: {
        host: 'hub-cloud.browserstack.com',
        port: 443
      },
      // More info on configuring capabilities can be found on:
      // https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities?tag=selenium-4
      desiredCapabilities: {
        'bstack:options' : {
          local: 'false',
          userName: '${BROWSERSTACK_USER}',
          accessKey: '${BROWSERSTACK_KEY}',
        }
      },

      disable_error_log: true,
      webdriver: {
        keep_alive: true,
        start_process: false
      }
    },

    'browserstack.chrome': {
      extends: 'browserstack',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions : {
          // This tells Chromedriver to run using the legacy JSONWire protocol
          // More info on Chromedriver: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/
          w3c: false
        }
      }
    },

    'browserstack.firefox': {
      extends: 'browserstack',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
      }
    },

    'browserstack.ie': {
      extends: 'browserstack',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'IE',
        browserVersion: '11.0',
        'bstack:options' : {
          os: 'Windows',
          osVersion: '10',
          local: 'false',
          seleniumVersion: '3.5.2',
          resolution: '1366x768'
        }
      }
    },

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Configuration for when using the Selenium service, either locally or remote,  |
    //  like Selenium Grid                                                           |
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    selenium: {
      // Selenium Server is running locally and is managed by Nightwatch
      selenium: {
        start_process: true,
        port: 4444,
        server_path: (Services.seleniumServer ? Services.seleniumServer.path : ''),
        cli_args: {
          'webdriver.gecko.driver': (Services.geckodriver ? Services.geckodriver.path : ''),
          'webdriver.chrome.driver': (Services.chromedriver ? Services.chromedriver.path : '')
        }
      }
    },

    'selenium.chrome': {
      extends: 'selenium',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions : {
          w3c: false
        }
      }
    },

    'selenium.firefox': {
      extends: 'selenium',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        'moz:firefoxOptions': {
          args: [
            // '-headless',
            // '-verbose'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function loadServices() {
  try {
    Services.seleniumServer = require('selenium-server');
  } catch (err) {}

  try {
    Services.chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
  } catch (err) {}

  try {
    Services.geckodriver = require('geckodriver');
  } catch (err) {}
}
```

Comment: Another post suggested add this block to the nightwatch configuration, but it produced no change.

`live_output: false,
silent: true,
output: true,
detailed_output: false,
disable_error_log: false,`

Comment: Show us your config file settings

Comment: @VladislavBulanov done

Comment: Where exactly did you try to add `detailed_output: false` because I use it without an issue.

Comment: I tried those settings again and they worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Just to mark it as answered

You need to add `detailed_output: false` in your `nightwatch` config file.